# Access parsed nested JSON via keys in Qt C++

Tags: c++, json, c++11, dictionary, qt5

Here is an example of JSON:

```
 {
  "sets": [
   {
   "id": "123",
   "start": "Alpha",
   "end": "Theta",
   "units": [
   {
      "id": " A",
      "name": "nameA",
      "position": 1,
      "capacity": 7
    },
    {
      "id": "nameB",
      "name": "WWW4561",
      "position": 2,
      "capacity": 15
    }
    ]
  },
  {
    "id": "456",
    "start": "Beta",
    "end": "Zeta",
    "units": [
    {
      "id": "B",
      "name": "nameB",
      "position": 1,
      "capacity": 9
    },
    {
      "id": "F",
      "name": "nameF",
      "position": 1,
      "capacity": 18
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
}
```

I want to store the parsed data in a container such that I will be able to access any unit item from `units` given the `start` and `end` values of the `sets`. If I am not mistaken this should be done using a `dictionary`.

Currently, I can only iterate through the `sets` and the `units` only. 
Here is what I tried:

```
QNetworkReply *json_reply;
QJsonObject jsonObject= QJsonDocument::fromJson(json_reply->readAll()).object();
QJsonArray sets_array = jsonObject["sets"].toArray();
QJsonArray units_array = jsonObject[""].toArray(); // explicitly empty array

int idx = 0;
for (const QJsonValue& set_val: sets_array)
{
    QJsonObject set_loopObj = set_val.toObject();

    qDebug() << "\nset" << idx;
    qDebug() << " id:" << set_loopObj["id"].toString();
    qDebug() << "start:" << set_loopObj["start"].toString();
    qDebug() << "end:" << set_loopObj["end"].toString();

        units_array.append(set_loopObj["units"].toArray());

    int idy = 0;
    for (const QJsonValue& unit_val: units_array)
    {
        QJsonObject unit_loopObj = unit_val.toObject();

        qDebug() << "\nunit";
        qDebug() << "id:" << unit_loopObj["id"].toString();
        qDebug() << "name:" << unit_loopObj["name"].toString();
        qDebug() << "position:" << unit_loopObj["position"].toDouble();
        qDebug() << "capacity:" << unit_loopObj["capacity"].toDouble();

        ++idy;
    }
    ++idx;
}
qDebug() << "\nsets_array" << sets_array;
qDebug() << "\nunits_array" << units_array;
```

*UPDATE*

For example, I expect that by giving `"Alpha","Theta"` to get both units of the first set as an array so that I should be able to access individual units by giving an indice (e.g. 1 for the 2nd unit).

I would also want to get the rest of the sets info (`id`) as well when providing the `"Alpha, Theta"` keys.

Please provide code in your answers cause I am newbie.

Comment: I don't know how you expect your resulting object to look. Please post an example.

Comment: @erip Good point. I updated my description.

Comment: And the (start, end) tuple will be unique, yes?

Comment: @erip Yes, unique. However, I made it a tuple for the purposes of this example; please consider the keys being 3 values or more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
units_array.append(set_loopObj["units"].toArray());

int idy = 0;
for (const QJsonValue& unit_val: units_array)
{
    QJsonObject unit_loopObj = unit_val.toObject();
```

When using `append` on `units_array`, you add the whole value passed as argument as a single element at the end of the array. Your for-loop is then filling `unit_val` with the current element, so the whole array, which you try to read as an object.

I think what you wanted to achieve is:

```
units_array = set_loopObj["units"].toArray();

int idy = 0;
for (const QJsonValue& unit_val: units_array)
{
    QJsonObject unit_loopObj = unit_val.toObject();
```

Here you can just remove `units_array` and write:

```
int idy = 0;
for (const QJsonValue& unit_val: set_loopObj["units"].toArray())
{
    QJsonObject unit_loopObj = unit_val.toObject();
```

You can do the same for `sets_array` and write:

```
int idx = 0;
for (const QJsonValue& set_val: jsonObject["sets"].toArray())
{
    QJsonObject set_loopObj = set_val.toObject();
```

About storing the data, first declare structures to represent your data:

```
struct MyUnit
{
    QString id;
    QString name;
    int position;
    int capacity;
};

struct MySet
{
    QString id;
    QString start;
    QString end;
    QVector<MyUnit> units;
};
```

You can then use something like that:

```
QMap<QPair<QString, QString>, MySet> data;

for (const QJsonValue& set_val: jsonObject["sets"].toArray())
{
    QJsonObject set_loopObj = set_val.toObject();

    // parse id, start, and end

    QVector<MyUnit> units;

    for (const QJsonValue& unit_val: set_loopObj["units"].toArray())
    {
        QJsonObject unit_loopObj = unit_val.toObject();

        // parse id, name, position, and capacity

        units.append(MyUnit{id, name, position, capacity});
    }

    data.insert(qMakePair(start, end), MySet{id, start, end, units});
}
```

And use it:

```
MySet at_set = data.value(qMakePair("Alpha", "Theta"));

qDebug() << at_set.id;

for(MyUnit at_unit: at_set.units)
{
    // use at_unit
}
```

Comment: It worked with the previous version with the `{}`. However, I am not able to make the `set at_set = ...` line to not error. I tried `std::set` and `QSet` with no success.  Please any help with that?

Comment: `set` is the type previously defined `struct set`: nothing to do with `std::set`, nor `QSet`. However, the name may conflict with `std::set`: I edited my answer with less ambiguous names

Comment: Oh I see, my bad. Now I get `at is not  a member of QMap<QPair<QString,QString>` ... I tried with square brackets but I get other errors `cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays`

Comment: My bad, this time ^^. `QMap` has no `at` method, it's `value`. I edited my answer

Comment: Now I get `cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays` .. perhaps you could instead provide a version where not a `QPair` is the key, but a list of 3 values like `{id,start,end} ?? Sorry for all these questions/issues.

Comment: I compiled the code on rextester.com for visual before posting. Did you use exactly the code in my answer? When you have an issue, please precise the code pointed by the compiler, I can't know what's going on just with the error message. Which line of code is causing the error ?

Comment: On line `MySet at_set = data.value(qMakePair("Alpha", "Theta"));` I get the following errors: `cannot specify explicit initializer for arrays` with `error: C2075: 'QPair<char [14],char [12]>::first': array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list` AND `error: C2075: 'QPair<char [14],char [12]>::second': array initialization requires a brace-enclosed initializer list`. It may be an issue with the `QPair` that's why I think if you could revise your code to not have pairs but list of `{id,start,end}` would maybe be wise. Thanks for your time

Comment: It's an issue of implicit template instantiation: without explicit parameters, the line is generating a `QPair<char[14], char[12]>` instead of `QPair<QString, QString>`. You can use `qMakePair({"Alpha"}, {"Theta"})`, maybe you will need to be more explicit using `QString{"Alpha"}`. If you want `{id, start, end}` as key, do it yourself. You have more than a starting point here :)

Answer (score 1):

I'd definitely break this into two tasks. The first subtask to to actually grab the appropriate object by its start and end.

```
QJsonObject find_by_start_and_end(const QJsonObject& obj, 
                                  const QString& start, 
                                  const QString& end) {

    QJsonArray sets_array = jsonObject["sets"].toArray();


    // For every object in the array, check if its start and end are the target.
    // If so return it.

    for(const auto& set_obj: sets_array) {
        QJsonObject set = set_obj.toObject();
        if(set["start"].toString() == start && set["end"].toString() == end) {
            return set;
        }
    }

  // If there are no matches, return an empty object.
  return QJsonObject{};
}
```

Now you can search by (start, end)  tuple--what a great feeling. By grabbing this entire object, you have all the information about it: the start, the end, the id, and all the units.

Now you just need to create a function that uses this helper to index into the units array appropriately.

```
QJsonObject get_kth_unit_by_start_and_end(const QJsonObject& obj, 
                                          const QString& start, 
                                          const QString& end,
                                          const std::size_t k) {
    // get the target by start and end tuple
    const QJsonObject target_obj = find_by_start_and_end(obj, start, end);

    // If the target is empty, the `units` array will not exist.
    if(target_obj.empty())
        return target_obj;

    // get the units array from that returned target
    QJsonArray units = target_obj["units"].toArray();

    if(units.size() <= k) {
       throw std::runtime_exception("Invalid k.");
    }

    // return the kth unit object.
    return units[k].toObject();
}
```

I haven't tested this; however, this should give you a good start.